# How does Hurl Through Hell work in Mechanus?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, class

The variant rule for Mechanus states that all rolls made there are automatically the average. However, what happens when a Fiend Pact Warlock uses their Hurl Through Hell feature there?

Can they not at all, does the creature take 55 points of psychic damage automatically, or does the player still roll the 10d10?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The wording of Hurl Through Hell **suggests** that the damage is taken **when the spell ends**.

> **At the end of your next turn, the target returns** to the space it previously occupied, or the nearest unoccupied space. If the target is not a fiend, it **takes 10d10 psychic damage** as it reels from its horrific experience.

I read it as "the target returns, then takes damage as the trauma overwhelms it". From a role-playing perspective, you could argue that the little roadtrip through hell it took is such a supernatural experience that the target can't even perceive it properly until it returns back to its familiar plane.

Should you choose to accept this reasoning, then the damage roll would succumb to the same rules as the other rolls.

However, such ruling is not immediately obvious, and the wording on Hurl Through Hell is still ambiguous enough that the players and/or the DM might feel more comfortable imagining the damage taking place in Hell. In that case the specific rules for Mechanus would be avoided. In the end, **it is up to the DM**.

Comment: I think your point that the damage happens after returning is clear and unambiguous. The "it's up for interpretation / to your DM" is actually preventing me from upvoting.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie perhaps my insecurity that the point is sufficiently strong stems from English not being my primary language. I wonder whether the sentence **strictly** implies that the events of appearing and taking damage are truly sequential, or if they're merely written out in that order with no meaning to be inferred from it. Combined with the natural understanding of "you take damage while damaging events happen to you" I believe it to be enough to cause valid counter arguments. I doubt that this case was considered when the rule was made, and in such occurrences the DM has the last word.

Comment: "I doubt that this case was considered when the rule was made, and in such occurrences the DM has the last word" should be appended to most answers that discuss unusual interactions of effects, I think. (More importantly, this answer makes two arguments: "The wording is unambiguous, but the wording only assumes the most usual case." Strengthening the second part of that would really help support your "it's up to the GM" point.)

Comment: I've gotta go with @SevenSidedDie on this one. Personally, I think any answer that says "It's the DM's call" is a bad answer, because DM's prerogative is a truism; stating it says nothing new or interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Well I think it's quite clear. 55 is the average when rolling 10d10 (10-100). It's the perfect expression of law and order. If you do this, then the outcome is always that.

Comment: If everything is average, and there is no variation, that is a provisional definition of Hell as both Lawful and Evil.

Comment: No I don't think so. Lawful means it's rules based and evil means selfish (for your own gain). The implication here is that lawful evil has ambition and you can do whatever you want so long as you don't break the rules and do what you are told. Mechanus is the realm of true neutral, where everything is balanced. There is no selfishness or selflessness, there is no inherent order other than what naturally occurs from not caring nor is there any chaos other than what naturally occurs by not caring.

Comment: A fair point, though we risk getting chatty if proceeding further.  Alignment discussions and cans of worms are found on the same shelf at the store. :-)