# What happens if the Fiend-patron warlock's Hurl Through Hell feature is used while in Hell?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, planes

The description of the [Fiend-patron warlock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/warlock#TheFiend)'s Hurl Through Hell feature says:

> Starting at 14th level, when you hit a creature with an attack, you can use this feature to instantly transport the target through the lower planes. The creature disappears and hurtles through a nightmare landscape.
>
> At the end of your next turn, the target returns to the space it previously occupied, or the nearest unoccupied space. If the target is not a fiend, it takes 10d10 psychic damage as it reels from its horrific experience.

What happens if a Warlock uses their Hurl Through Hell ability... while in any of the lower planes?  Does the target still make the trip through the *other* planes... possibly with an interlude directly overhead?  Or, since they're already in a lower plane, do they stay put?

---

*Related to, but distinct from, [How does Hurl Through Hell work in Mechanus?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70367/how-does-hurl-through-hell-work-in-mechanus) (which was about whether Mechanus' averaging of rolls affected the damage).*

Comment: I guess this is one of the (unforeseen) reasons the Lore has **nine** hells.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Hurl Through Hell work in Mechanus?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70367/how-does-hurl-through-hell-work-in-mechanus)

Comment: Also, Clockwork-Muse I am voting to close this question as a duplicate of the one you linked. It holds no demerit to you, in the Stack we tag questions with the same answer as duplicates so they can be linked. Duplicates are important because they enhance the search options for the knowledge.  - - -  For reviewers: Both questions can be considered part of a greater question: *"Does Hurl Through Hell works on other planes?"* -> The answer to both and the superquestion is the same: Yes it does.

Comment: @Mindwin I disagree. The Mechanus question does not ask whether it works, but whether the averaging effect of Mechanus applies (which means the question is really asking does the damage occur before or after you return to your original location). The matter of whether it works on other planes does not come up.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### It works as normal

[Abilities do what they say they do.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/107647/48827) Nothing in the ability description suggests that its functioning is impaired by being in Hell or another lower plane. To quote the ability,

> you can use this feature to instantly transport the target through the lower planes. The creature disappears and hurtles through a nightmare landscape.

There is no restriction on which plane you have to start in. Since there are multiple lower planes, there is no issue in hurling the target through a different plane. You could even hurtle the target through the current lower plane, as planes are large. If your DM is feeling comedic, they might even hurtle overhead (although too quickly to interact with), as the ability is very vague about the precise nature of the journey. The key point is that 'the creature *disappears*', and planar travel is involved.

Comment: I'd refrain from the comedic "hurling overhead through the combat mat". Probably some joker will take advantage and set a ready action to deal additional damage to the target.

Comment: You can only be on one layer of Hell at a time. So it could throw you through any of the other 8.

Comment: @Mindwin is this so bad? Seems like a strategy, not an exploit :)

Comment: @Mindwin, then you just tell them its too quick for you to react to even with a readied action.

Comment: @cbauer when you get something to do what it was not intended to do, it is an exploit.

Comment: That means that literally every house rule that has ever existed is an exploit...

Comment: @Mindwin A player can only ready an action if they anticipate the trigger. The DM should not signal that it happens prior to it happening; it's probably funny only once so it won't be repeatable; and they can hurtle somewhere still in view but out of reach and too fast to interact with. But superseding all of this is how the DM is feeling and how they read their players. If your players are likely to exploit this rather than accept the joke, then you would be well advised to refrain from it.

Comment: Sounds more like clever play to me, especially since it's a once-per-day ability.
Additionally, Would it really be so bad if they did? Would it even be optimal to do so most of the time? Readying an action has its own costs (spent reaction, no extra attack, etc), and it doesn't let you do much you couldn't do anyway. Plus, you could always just ready the attack until after they reappear, after all.

@Mindwin Your definition of exploit is broad enough to include a wide range of examples, but also so broad as to no longer be necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: Imagine what would happen to a devil's psyche if it was smashed through the utter chaos of a few layers of the Abyss!!

Answer (score -3):

Lots of D&D stuff is very literal, so read it literally.

You "instantly transport the target **through** the lower plane**s**" (the s is important because it makes it plural, not singular). "The creature disappears and *hurtles through* a nightmare landscape."

If you still don't get it, it says through the Lower Planes, meaning through multiple planes, not just sent to one plane (you can't choose). And it also states that they hurtle through, meaning they are being thrown across multiple planes at high speeds. Imagine those alien space ship rides at a fair when you get spun around so fast you get lifted up and you cant raise your arm for long - that is basically what's happening, but probably 10 times worse.

I'd find it hard for anything to take an action in those conditions.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! There might be a valid answer in here somewhere, but as it currently is written it is far too unclear and aggressive. Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Also note that there is no swearing on this site. I have removed it from your answer.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose  Shouldn't it be "Hurl through Heck"?

Comment: @PinkSweetener Hell is not a swear word, it's the name of a place described in the game. D&D has a Plane in the rules called the Nine Hells, based off the view of Hell presented in Dante's Divine Comedy.